# Characterization of the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

Let $R \neq 0$ be a ring which may not be commutative and may not have an identity.
Suppose $R$ satisfies the following conditions.

1) $a^2 = a$ for every element $a$ of $R$.

2) $ab \neq 0$ whenever $a \neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$.

Is $R$ isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Every Boolean ring is commutative. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/how-to-show-that-every-boolean-ring-is-commutative). So the part "may not be commutative" is immaterial.

Comment: I noticed that someone serially upvoted for my questions and answers including this one.
While I appreciate them, I would like to point out that serial upvotes are automatically reversed by the system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assume that $a,b\neq0$.
We have 
$$
0=abab-ab=(aba-a)b,
$$
so $a=aba$. Therefore
$$
0=a-aba=a^2-aba=a(a-ba).
$$
So we also see that $a=ba$. 
Repeating the dose once more
$$
0=ba-a=ba-a^2=(b-a)a\implies b=a.
$$
Thus your rng has only one non-zero element. As there are no zero-divisors that non-zero element is an identity, and it follows that $R\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Beautiful proof!

Comment: I think I am going to dub proofs of this sort "washing machine argument" because you wash, rinse, spin, repeat. After two-three cycles the proof comes out clean from all the dirt it had at first!

Answer (score 2):

Let $a \neq 0$ be an element of $R$.
It suffices to show that $a$ is an identity.
So we would like to show first that $ab = b$ for any element $b$ of $R$.
It suffices to show that $a(ab) = ab$ thanks to the condition 2).
But this is obvious thanks to the condition 1).
Similiarly we can show that $ba = b$.

Comment: +1 Yeah, it is unnecessary to use idempotency of $ab$ :-)