# Yet another characterization of the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R \neq 0$ be a ring which may not be commutative and may not have an identity.
Suppose $R$ satisfies the following conditions.

1) $a^2 = a$ for every element $a$ of $R$.

2) $R$ has no two-sided ideals other than $0$ and $R$.

Is $R$ isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $a+a=0$ for all $a\in R$, since $a+a=(a+a)^2=a+a+a+a$;
- $ab=ba$ for all $a,b\in R$, since $a+b=(a+b)^2=a+ab+ba+b$ so $ab=-ba=ba$;
- $a=b$ for $a,b\in R\setminus\{0\}$. Namely $b\in aR$ and $b\in aR$ because $\{0\}$ and $R$ are the only (two-sided) ideals, whence there exist $x,y$ with $ax=b$ and $a=yb$; then $a=yb=yb^2=ab=a^2x=ax=b$.

Since $R\neq\{0\}$ there is exactly one nonzero element of $R$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe so.  By the first condition, the ring is commutative.  By the second, it is simple Artinian, and therefore semisimple.  Then, it must be a product of matrix rings over division rings.

Commutativity then shows that all matrix groups have dimension $1$, and that all division rings are fields.  Finally, with no two-sided ideals, we can't have the product of two or more fields, so we are left with just a field.

Finally, the polynomial $x^2-x$ can only have two solutions over this field, so the field must have only two elements.

Edit: As Matt E has pointed out, I've assumed that the ring is unital.  Finite boolean rings are always unital, so if a counterexample exists, it will be infinite.

Again, in the comments, Matt E has suggested we adjoin an identity element to the ring by considering $R'=\mathbb{F}_2\oplus R$ and defining multiplication by $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ab,ad+bc+bd)$.  This makes $(1,0)$ the identity element.  Now, using a modified version of the argument above, we can show $R'$ is a direct sum of two fields, so that $R$ is a field.

Comment: I'm sure it is simple, but how does the first condition imply commutativity?

Comment: @DanielFischer Expand $a^2+b^2=(a+b)=(a+b)^2$.

Comment: The first condition makes the ring into a Boolean ring, and these are always commutative.  To see this, consider the implications of the two equalities $a+a=(a+a)^2$ and $a+b=(a+b)^2$.

Comment: Dear Jared, At least at face value your argument seems to assume that $R$ admits an identity (since it uses concepts like Artinianness, Artin--Wedderburn theory, etc, which *prime facie* apply to rings with $1$).  Regards,

Comment: @user1 That gives me $ab + ba = 0$. Setting $b = a$ in that gives $a + a = 0$ (for all $a$), and therefore $ba = -ab = ab$. Yup, I was right, it is simple. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Dear Jared, What if you add an identity by considering $\mathbb F_2 \oplus R$.   Then you still get a Boolean and Artinian ring, and your argument probably goes through.  What do you think? Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In $R$ 
$$
(1+a)^2=1+a
$$
implies $a=-a$. Further, 
$$
(a+b)^2=a+b
$$
implies $ab=-ba=ba$, so $R$ is commutative. Since each ideal $aS$ coincides with $R$ then for every $b$ the equation $ax=b$ is soluble, so $R$ is a field.

**Correction:** If $R$ has not $1$, the commutativity was proved in the comment of Jared (thank to Matt E and  Jonas Meyer for the remarks).

Comment: Dear Boris, $R$ is not assumed to assume an identity.  Regards,

Comment: [Jared comments](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452315/yet-another-characterizaion-of-the-field-mathbbz-2-mathbbz#comment972524_452319) with an alternative to considering $(1+a)^2$.

Comment: @  Matt E : Dear Matt, thank you. I corrected the answer.

Comment: @  Jonas Meyer : Thank you very much.

Comment: How does the fact that $ax=b$ is always solvable for $x$ (when $a\neq0$) imply the existence of an identity for multiplication (which is necessary for being a field)?

Comment: @ Marc van Leeuwen: Multiply by $a$:               $$ab=a^2b=ab=b,$$ so $a$ is an identity.

Comment: @BorisNovikov: I don't understand your comment. What expression or equality do I multiply by $a$? And how could I possibly I extract from some relation between particular $a,b$ that $a$ is a global $1$ element? However, see my answer.

Comment: @ Marc van Leeuwen: Multiply $ax=b$ by $a$: $$ab=a^2x=ax=b$$. This is true for all $b$, so $a$ is a global $1$. Of course, your answer is also right.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is commutative as shown in the Marc van Leeuwen's answer.
Let $a, b$ be non-zero elements of $R$.
It suffices to prove $ab \neq 0$ thanks to [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448613/characterization-of-the-field-mathbbz-2-mathbbz).
Since $a = a^2 \in aR$, $aR \neq 0$.
Hence the ideal $I = \{x \in R |\ ax = 0\}$ cannot be $R$.
Hence $I = 0$ as desired.