# Show that a Boolean ring is a commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, boolean-ring

I have a question about (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10279)'s proof to this. I also asked as a comment but I am unsure whether it will be replied to since the post was made 8 years ago?

My question to their proof is: How does $x+xy+yx+y=x+y$ imply $xy=yx$? Doesn't $xy=yx$ imply $xy-yx=0$, and so how is $xy+yx=0$?

Comment: Timothy Wagner's answer to the question you cite shows that every Boolean ring is of characteristic $2$, so $xy+xy=0$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show that every Boolean ring is commutative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/how-to-show-that-every-boolean-ring-is-commutative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Boolean ring $(-1)^2=-1$, so $1=-1$. In particular $$xy-yx=xy+yx$$

Comment: I see this now! Thanks so much for making me understand in a clear easy manner.

Comment: @numericalorange My pleasure!