# How many ring homomorphisms from field to field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Abstract algebra related problem
Let R be a non zero ring with identity such that $a^ 2 =a$, for all $a\in R$. Then which of the following statements are true.

- $(1)$ there is no such ring.
- $(2)$ $2a=0$ for all $a\in R$
- $(3)$ $3a=0$ for all $a\in R$
- $(4)$ $Z/2Z$ is subring of $R$

Comment: We can rule out $(1)$ because $\mathbb Z_2$ has the desired property.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10274/how-to-show-that-every-boolean-ring-is-commutative?noredirect=1&lq=1). So $R$ has characteristic $2$ and is commutative.

Comment: 2 is true: $(a+1)^2 = a^2+2a+1=3a+1$ on the one hand, but on the other hand it is equal to $a+1$, so $2a = 0$.

Comment: By the way, the title of this question has nothing to do with its contents, as far as I can see.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I agree

Comment: $(3)$ must be wrong because $2a=0$ and $3a=0$ would imply $a=0$, but $a$ has an identity element.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Naturally. We posted those statements at the same time.